# How to extract value from key of json format using python

Tags: python, json

My JSON response is as follows:

```
[{"interface":"WAN 1","status":"Active","ip":"192.168.254.3","gateway":"192.168.254.1","publicIp":"206.59.240.69","dns":"192.168.254.1","vlan":2,"usingStaticIp":false}]
```

I wanted to extract the value of "status" but getting the below error:

```
TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Code snippet:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
print(response["status"])
```

Can somebody please help me to extract the value of `'status'`?

Comment: looks like your response is an array. You would want to access the `status` property at the index you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the JSON first:

```
import json

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data["status"])
```

Note that based on the JSON response sample provided, the response is a list, in which case you would have to print `data[0]["status"]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anoop. data[0]["status"] worked for me.